How can I approximate a cubic root?
I have to do a maths exercise that requires me to frame √3 with an amplitude of 10^-5.
Using the sweep method and Python.
I'm French so I don't know if "sweep" is the right word.
Earlier in the exercise, I was given some hints:
√3 is a solution of the equation x^2 - 3 = 0
and I need to reach the point where x*y is negative
So I tried this:
x = 1
y = 1 + 10**-5 
while (x** 2 - 3) * (y** 2 - 3) >= 0 :  
    x = x + 10**-5
    y = y + 10**-5
print(x)

It gave the correct answer: 1.73205 so I can frame 1.73205 < √3 < 1.73206
Do you know other ways to do this kind of maths ? Is there a "sweep" function for example? (Sorry if wrong word)

note: don't use 10**-5. Use 1e-5 instead

Use repeated bisection. Alternatively, just use math.cbrt. If you absolutely must use “sweep” start with coarse-grained intervals and then move finer.

@phuclv Why? Maybe they find 10**-5 clearer...

@Joundill What does that other question have to do with this?

'the equation x^2 - 3 = 0 and I need to reach the point where xy is negative"* - Where does y suddenly come from? That's not in the equation. Did you make it up yourself?

You're looking for "iterative optimization". Take a look at scipy.optimize package

@nocomment no, 1e-5 is correctly rounded, while 10**-5 might not, and it's much slower

@phuclv How much slower? Is it noticeable at all? Their 10**-5 gets compiled to byte code LOAD_CONST 5 (1e-05), so we're talking about a one-time calculation during compilation (if it's even a calculation... I could imagine the compiler to recognize the pattern and "rewrite" it to the corresponding float literal).


Do you know other ways to do this kind of maths

If you're tasked with the "sweep" method, you can build up your answer incrementally, starting with a large increment (one) and then progressively reducing the increment, e.g.,
In [73]: %reset -f
    ...: from fractions import Fraction as F
    ...: from decimal import Decimal as D
    ...: 
    ...: x = F(1,1); y = F(1,1); ten = F(10,1)
    ...: for exp in range(21):
    ...:     d = pow(ten, -exp)
    ...:     while (x*x-3)*(y*y-3) > 0:
    ...:         x, y = y, x+d
    ...:     y = x
    ...:     decimal = D(x.numerator)/D(x.denominator)
    ...:     fill = '0' if exp else '.'
    ...:     print('%2d'%(exp), str(decimal).ljust(exp+2, fill))
 0 1.
 1 1.7
 2 1.73
 3 1.732
 4 1.7320
 5 1.73205
 6 1.732050
 7 1.7320508
 8 1.73205080
 9 1.732050807
10 1.7320508075
11 1.73205080756
12 1.732050807568
13 1.7320508075688
14 1.73205080756887
15 1.732050807568877
16 1.7320508075688772
17 1.73205080756887729
18 1.732050807568877293
19 1.7320508075688772935
20 1.73205080756887729352

In [74]: 

As a floating point number has only limited precision, in the code I've used two different Python standard libraries, fractions and  decimals, to be able to compute sqrt(3) with an arbitrary precision.
All the numbers, x y and ten, are initialized as Fractions, meaning that they are always represented as the ratio of two Python integers (i.e., arbitrary precision) and all the intermediate results are represented as Fractions too.
Eventually the Decimal class is used to represent our result as a floating point with arbitrary precision.
I played a bit with formatting to have a perfectly trapezoidal output, but you can simply print(exp, decimal) if you so want.

I think you want >= 0 to be > 0

@MadPhysicist I'm working with rational numbers and the root is irrational, so the product is always different from zero, but when  I try to solve x*x -289/100=0 (x=17/10) the ≥ code goes into an infinite loop, so you're correct. Thank you for correcting me!

I have corrected my code according to @MadPhysicist remark.

Yup. It's not just rational numbers, but specifically powers of 2 down to 2^-53 or so. When your delta is below that, it can't be resolved in a float and will be recorded as zero. This is also one way you can find epsilon for your float representation of choice
